# Spring 5 immutable form to use an all arg constructor when there is No argument constructor as well

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

In an immutable class/object I have one no argument constructor initializing values to default/null, and another required argument constructor that initializes all the values to arguments from constructor.

When using the form binding (by specifying in request parameter in controller), spring is always calling the no argument constructor and not initializing the values. How can I ensure spring to call the required argument constructor only?

This is in spring version 5.1.5. I have tried adding @ConstructorProperties on the "required argument constructor" as well, but to no avail.

---

My immutable form/bean object:

```java
public class ImmutableObj {
    private final Integer id;
    private final String name;

    // no arg constructor
    // spring calls this one when resolving request params
    public ImmutableObj() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    // required args constructor
    // I want spring to call this one when resolving request params
    @ConstructorProperies({"id", "name"})
    public ImmutableObj(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And my controller:

```java
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping("myStuff")
    public String getMyStuff(ImmutableObj requestParams) {
        // here the value of request params
        // has nulls due to no arg constructor being called 
        return "someStuff";
    }
}
```

---

When calling "/myStuff?id=123&name=hello"

Expected - `requestParams.getId()=123, requestParams.getName()=hello`

Actual - `requestParams.getId()=null, requestParams.getName()=null`

---

UPDATE!!!!!!!!!!!!!

After removing the no arg constructor, I'm now running into issues for compositions:

```java
public class ImmutableObj {
    private final SomeOtherObj someOtherObj;

    public ImmutableObj(SomeOtherObj obj) {
        someOtherObj = obj;
    }
}

public class SomeOtherObj {
    private final Integer id;
    private final String name;

    public SomeOtherObj(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And spring throws:

```
Could not instantiate property type [SomeOtherObj] to auto-grow nested property path; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: SomeOtherObj.<init>()
```

Comment: Why do you have the default constructor at all?

Comment: I have a use-case where we need to return an "empty" object if not found. Now that I think of it I can use a static method like `ImmutableObject.empty()`, doooooh. Either way I wanted to know if there is a way to direct to spring to choose a required-args constructor, instead of the no arg one?

Comment: @akk202 what was the issue? (you removed the comment)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I updated it in my original question. I didn't remove any comments.

Comment: You cannot do that when using data-binding. Spring requires either properties according to the java bean specification or use direct field access . It will NOT use the all args constructor to bind arguments coming from the web to a form, it will always use the default no-args constructor. In fact that is a requirement for objects being used as form objects. (Not for classes used as beans in the application context).

Comment: @akk202 how do you make a request for the update?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I just edited my post and added "UPDATED!!!!!!!" as a follow up question.

Comment: @akk202 I saw it. How did you make Spring throw an exception? What did you do? What request did you make?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Oh i changed to make request on a more complex form. something like `"myStuff?someOtherObj.id=123&someOtherObj.name=hello"` following java beans naming conventions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Spring is always calling the no argument constructor and not initializing the values.

When Spring see that the class has more than one constructor, it will go search for a no-argument one. If Spring doesn't find it, it will throw an exception.

When Spring see that the class has exactly one constructor, it will take it regardless of a number of parameters it has.

> How can I ensure spring to call the required argument constructor only?

The only way is to have only one constructor in the class. To make it unambiguous for Spring.

As a side note,

1. You don't need `@ConstructorProperies({"id", "name"})` if the field names correspond to the URL parameter names. Spring can figure that out.
2. ```
   public ImmutableObj() {
       this(null, null);
   }
   ```

is not a good idea. `ImmutableObj.empty()` would be better.

As a bonus, if you like to see what's going on behind the scenes, here's the snippet I was talking about

```
if (ctor == null) {
  Constructor<?>[] ctors = clazz.getConstructors();
  if (ctors.length == 1) {
    ctor = ctors[0];
  } else {
    try {
      ctor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException var10) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("No primary or default constructor found for " + clazz, var10);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate the insight. Thanks!. I'm now trying to solve a related issue with composition (form containing a form). And this time spring complains not finding a default constructor?? (see my update to the original question)

Comment: If you want to pass constructor argument automatically, you should have initialized beans in the Spring context and put `@Autowired` annotation on the constructor that need to initialize arguments when invokes. Spring doesn't know how to invoke that constructor, if Spring can't find beans to initialize constructor parameters.

Comment: This will only work for beans defined in the context. It will NOT work when doing data binding from a form to an object.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks! will keep that in mind. I have resorted to having a DTO just for spring forms and converting it to immutable for my needs. Thought I'd avoid it but looks like there is no other way out for compositions

Comment: @SachithDickwella I'm not working with spring beans. just forms (request params -> decorated forms)